# LLVM IR C++ API create anonymous global variable

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

How can I create an anonymous global variable in LLVM IR C++ API?

I can create a named global variable as follows:

```cpp
GlobalVariable *createGlobalVariable(
    Module *module,
    Type *type,
    std::string name
) {
    module->getOrInsertGlobal(name, type);
    return module->getNamedGlobal(name);
}
```

For example:

```cpp
auto context = new LLVMContext();
auto module = new Module("Module", *context);

auto type = IntegerType::getInt32Ty(*context);
auto globalVariable = createGlobalVariable(
    module,
    type,
    "globalVariableName"
);
auto constantInt = ConstantInt::getIntegerValue(
    type, 
    APInt(32, 42)
);
globalVariable->setInitializer(constantInt);
module->dump();
```

It will generate:

```
; ModuleID = 'Module'
source_filename = "Module"

@globalVariableName = global i32 42
```

How can I create an anonymous global variable?

I would like to generate somethings like:

```
; ModuleID = 'Module'
source_filename = "Module"

@0 = global i32 42
```

`@0` is a unique identifiers

Comment: I don't know LLVM IR, but in C++ code you would put the variable in an anonymous namespace. That doesn't really make the variable have no name, but have a name that cannot be known from the outside (close enough?).

Comment: Passing `""` as the name should work, although I can't test it right now. Also you can't use `getNamedGlobal` to get the variable back, if you do it this way.

Comment: @IlCapitano It work, `getOrInsertGlobal("", type)` give a unique identifiers `@0` `@1` ... but it return `Constant*`, how can I set the value / initializer?

Comment: @CWKSC see the [docs](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1GlobalVariable.html#af9ea64c7dae47dcfa2c9f5775fb5915d). You can create an instance of `GlobalVariable` from a `Constant*` using one of its constructors.

Comment: @IlCapitano Yes! I just find this way too, thank you :D. Let me write an answer for notes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In comment, @IlCapitano said that `Pass "" as name`

I try

```cpp
auto context = new LLVMContext();
auto module = new Module("Module", *context);

auto type = IntegerType::getInt32Ty(*context);
auto constant = module->getOrInsertGlobal("", type);
module->dump();
```

It generates:

```
; ModuleID = 'Module'
source_filename = "Module"

@0 = external global i32
```

But if I set initializer, will be `Segmentation fault`

```cpp
auto constant = module->getOrInsertGlobal("", type);
auto anonymousGlobalVariable = module->getNamedGlobal(constant->getName());
anonymousGlobalVariable->setInitializer(constantInt);
// -> Segmentation fault
```

The correct way is creating GlobalVariable by using constructor:

```cpp
auto context = new LLVMContext();
auto module = new Module("Module", *context);

auto type = IntegerType::getInt32Ty(*context);
auto constantInt = ConstantInt::getIntegerValue(type, APInt(32, 42));
auto anonymousGlobalVariable = new GlobalVariable(
    *module, 
    type, 
    false, 
    GlobalValue::CommonLinkage, 
    constantInt, 
    ""
);
module->dump();
```

Nice

```
; ModuleID = 'Module'
source_filename = "Module"

@0 = common global i32 42
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm kinda new to the llvm c++ api, but using the llvm toolchain, we can determine how c++ static global variables are represented in llvm ir (assuming your intention is to generate unique identifiers among multiple translation units (i.e. fix name collisions when linking multiple llvm ir files together)).

Given `non-static.cpp`:

```cpp
int x = 0;
```

`clang -S -emit-llvm non-static.cpp` emits this for our global `x`:

```
[...]
@x = dso_local global i32 0, align 4
[...]
```

Given `static.cpp`:

```cpp
static int x = 0;
int main() {
    return x; // refer to `x` so llvm doesn't optimize it away
}
```

`clang -S -emit-llvm static.cpp` emits this for our global `x`:

```
[...]
@_ZL1x = internal global i32 0, align 4
[...]
```

Note the presence of the `internal` linkage type.

To set this modifier using the llvm c++ api, you have to call one of [`GlobalVariable`](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1GlobalVariable.html#af9ea64c7dae47dcfa2c9f5775fb5915d)'s constructors and pass [`llvm::GlobalValue::LinkageTypes::InternalLinkage`](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1GlobalValue.html#aedfa75f0c85c4aa85b257f066fbea57c) to the `Linkage` parameter.